# How does Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide() change the execution order in multicore?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr, interlocked

if we run the below code with release mode

```
class Program
{
    static volatile int x, y, a, b;
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var t1 = Task.Run(Test1);
            var t2 = Task.Run(Test2);
            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            if (a == 0 && b == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", a, b);
            }
            x = y = a = b = 0;
        }
    }

    static void Test1()
    {
        x = 1; 
        //Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide()   comment out first
        a = y;
    }

    static void Test2()
    {
        y = 1;
        b = x;
    }
}
```

we can see a lot of 0,0 printed because we dont' use any memory barrier.
However, if we use `Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide()` (uncomment it), then we won't see any 0,0 output.

However, if I change the order in `Test2` as

```
class Program
{
    static volatile int x, y, a, b;
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var t1 = Task.Run(Test1);
            var t2 = Task.Run(Test2);
            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            if (a == 0 && b == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", a, b);
            }
            x = y = a = b = 0;
        }
    }

    static void Test1()
    {
        x = 1;   // 2
        Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide();  // 3
        a = y;   // 4
    }

    static void Test2()
    {

        b = x;   // 1

        y = 1;   // 5
    }
}
```

I mark the execution order, threadA execute 1, so `b` is 0, then a context switch happens threadB execute 2,3,4, and after 4 is executed, `a` is 0, then threadA continute to execute 5. so we should be getting 0,0 printed but there is none, why is that? how does Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide() change the execution order so that no 0,0 printed regardsless of `Test2` being

```
static void Test2()
{
   y = 1;
   b = x;
}
```

or

```
static void Test2()
{
   b = x;
   y = 1;   
}
```

Comment: You seem to think there is any global ordering. This is false, CPUs do things concurrently all the time. The fiction that instructions are run in-order is only valid for a single thread. I do not think your example proves much, it can still be faulty even if 0,0 is never printed. Multi threaded programs are notorious for failing only when you least want them to. I would recommend using a lock for guaranteed ordering. Memory barriers in general are fairly specialized synchronization primitives, MemoryBarrierProcessWide even more so.